# Concatenate MIB variable label to another query result from other two MIB variables in Prometheus

Tags: grafana, prometheus

We have a situation where I want to add a MIB variable label to another query. This another query gives me the value result that I want but I need to add the label from first variable in order to then sort them by what I want (for example just as we do it with ***instance*** label).

E.g.

**variable1{alert,env, index, instance, ..., labelneeded}**

**variable2{alert,env, index, instance}**

For example there I wanted to get the index of both and somehow add the label-needed by 
I tried the following queries but they didnt work after they are giving me both variables with its labels but not concatenated together so my question is if there is a possibility to concatenate them together?

Query example:

```
max by {index, instance} (variable2 * 5) or max(variable2) by (labelneeded, index, instance)
```

Thank you in advance :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to explain how to merge labels labels from two metrics, I'll take a common case:

- a *value* metric `value{instance="foo",a_label="bar"} 42`
- an *info* metric `info{instance="foo",version="1.2.3",another="bar"} 1`

Info metrics (such as version, compiler, ...) have value 1 such that you can apply operators between the metrics:

```
value * on(instance) group_left(version) info
```

Result

```
{instance="foo",a_label="bar",version="1.2.3"} 42
```

The parameter(s) of [`on()` keyword](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#one-to-one-vector-matches) specify the criteria(s) for matching the info and the parameter(s) of [`group_left()` operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches) specify the labels to pull.

It can happens that the metric you want to pull from doesn't have value 1. In that case, you can use the [`bool` modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators) with a comparison always true to obtain 1:

```
other_metric{instance="foo",baz="void"} 0.5555
value * on(instance) group_left(baz) other_metric != bool NaN
```

Result

```
{instance="foo",a_label="bar",baz="void"} 42
```